# How to include shadows when publishing to Artifactory? (Gradle)

Tags: java, gradle, artifactory, publishing

So for a little context: I have recently set up an Artifactory repository and I am new to working with Artifactory, everything I have been doing thus far has been from their user guide.

Now for the question: I would like to deploy a master plugin to Artifactory, but have it also include the shadowed dependencies on this using Gradle.

I have a general idea of deploying, and I have done so before, though I do not know how to deploy the code with the shadowed dependencies included and I am looking for some guidance that will allow me to do this.

I have included the parts of build.gradle that I believe is relevant for this:

```
artifactory {
    contextUrl = "${artifactory_contextUrl}"
    publish {
        repository {
            repoKey = 'sunace'
            username = [REDACTED]
            password = "${artifactory_password}"
        }
        defaults {
            publishConfigs('archives', 'published')

            properties {
                all 'fun.sunace.master:MasterController:1.?:*@*', key2: 'val2', key3: 'val3'
            }
            publishBuildInfo = true
            publishArtifacts = true
            publishPom = true
            publishIvy = false
            publishForkCount = 8
        }
    }

    clientConfig.setIncludeEnvVars(true)
    clientConfig.info.addEnvironmentProperty('time.published',new java.util.Date().toString())
    clientConfig.info.setBuildName('MasterController')
    clientConfig.info.setBuildNumber('' + new Random(System.currentTimeMillis()).nextInt(20000))
    clientConfig.timeout = 600
    resolve {
        repository {
            repoKey = 'gradle-dev'
            username = [REDACTED]
            password = "${artifactory_password}"
            maven = true

        }
    }
}
```

If you need anything else, just ask and I will amend the post with the requested assets.

Thanks to all those who help!

Comment: You should try bintray‘s gradle plugin.

Comment: I would, though I don't use Bintray's service, the reason being that I don't have $150 per month for private repositories, I use Artifactory since it requires authentication for distribution (at least to my knowledge) and that it can be on-prem (which I have), which is what I want for closed projects. If you happen to know anything similar then, by all means, I would love to know, since I am still learning around this space